# Why do we require a stochastic integral to be a martingale?

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, self-learning, martingales

Kuo, in his book "Introduction to Stochastic Integration" ( pages 37-41 ) to justify certain choices in the definition of a stochastic integral:

$$I(t)=\int_0^t f(s,\omega)dB(s,\omega)$$

where $B$ is a Brownian motion and $f$ a stochastic process (with certain characteristics), emphasizes that some decisions are done so that $I(t)$ is a martingale.

For example:

- Kuo observes that:

$$\int_0^t B(1,\omega)dB(s,\omega)$$

should not be defined by any integration scheme, since the value that we expect from a reasonable integration theory would be:

$$I(t,\omega)=B(1,\omega)B(t,\omega)$$

, and this is not a martingale, since the expectation value depends on $t$. From here Kuo "decides" to restrict $f$ to be adapted ;

- An other example is, if we try to calculate $\int_0^t B(t)dB(t)$ with a discrete approximation:

$$\int_0^t B(t)dB(t) \sim I^{\Delta}=\sum_i B(\tau_i)(B(t_{i})-B(t_{i-1}))$$

Only when the evaluation point $\tau_i$ is equal to $t_{i-1}$, than the limit of $I^{\Delta}$ in $L^2$ defines a martingale, and from here Kuo decides that the evaluation point should be on the left ( so the Ito and not Stratonovich choice ).

I understand from the first chapters that the Wiener or Stjeltes integral ( for $f$ deterministic in $L^2$ or of bounded variation respectively ) return an integral w.r.t. $B$ that is a martingale. So one could proceeed "by analogy". But I do not think this is the real reason. So here the questions:

- Why do we require (oder at least Kuo) $I(t)$ to be a martingale ?
- What are some applications of the martingale property (or useful properties of the resulting integration scheme resulting from it) in this context ?

Comment: I appreciate feedback. I may also remove my question, if I understand the reason for the downvote :)

Comment: "Why do we require $I(t)$ to be a martingale?" is a strange question.  The Itô integral is defined in such a way that may give a martingale because it's a useful property.  In contrast, the Stratonovich integral is defined in such a way that the chain rule applies because it's a useful property.  Which property you prefer is up to you, but we may study both.

Comment: Also on a side note, I think the notation $I(t)=\int_0^tf(s,\omega)dB(s,\omega)$ is misleading because it somewhat implies that we are integrating pathwise for each $\omega$, which I'm sure you know is impossible because of the unbounded variation of Brownian motion paths. So I guess a more suitable notation would be $I(t)=\int_0^tf(s)dB(s)$, of course, with the agreement that $I(t)$ is random.

Comment: @UserA Thank you both. I am learning, so first of all if I knew all the answers I would just answer and not make questions :D (see tag self-learning ) So for the notation, this is the notation of Kuo. I think you may find many notations out there. I chose to report Kuo notation to emphasize that f is a stochastic process. Than ok it "passes on" a wrong message I agree...

Comment: @Brian Moehring Thanks a lot. I understand the part "it is a useful property". Probably than I will learn later in the book "why" this property is so useful.

Comment: @Thomas I personally think it is a reasonable question, provided that you specify which 'decisions' or assumptions you believe are too restricting.

Comment: @UserA I clarified the "restrictions" that Kuo presents in his introductory chapter. Anyway already all the comments received here are useful for me. I have the impression that the utility of the martingale property could result clearer also when interpreting the integral as solving stochastic differential equations, but I have not a clear opinion...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could vaguely argue, from the point of view of real-life experiments, that the martingale property is useful to describe any phenomenon in which "any measurement I make at time $t$ is a 'good' approximation of a measurement I make at time $t+\tau$ for some small $\tau$".

The property $E[X_{t+\tau}\mid \mathcal{F}_t]=X_t$ means that $X_{t+\tau}$ will have same averages or expectations as $X_t$, given the accumulated information in $\mathcal{F}_t$. Implied by this is that  $E[X_t]$ does not change for all $t$. Could you think about some real life phenomenon modeled by a martingale? Perhaps a deteriorating sensor where $X_t$ denotes the error in the measurement at each $t$ for example? Or maybe $X_t$ describes the error a partially intoxicated person makes when asked to walk in a straight line? Even simpler, consider a discrete process $\{X_n\}$ where $X_n$ denotes your gain after tossing a fair coin $n$ times, assuming you get 1 if heads and -1 if tails. This process can be shown to be a Martingale, which makes intuitive sense.

In your question, you also ask why we use a property such as $\{f_t\}$ is $\mathcal{F}_t$ adapted. Note that $X_t$ being $\mathcal{F}_t$-adapted implies that $E[X_t\mid \mathcal F_t]=X_t$, ie the 'information accumulated up to time $t$ in $\mathcal{F}_t$ is sufficient to determine the value of $f_t$ on all $A\in\mathcal{F}_t$'. So for example if $\mathcal{F}_t=\bigcup_{0\leq s\leq t}\sigma(B_s)$, where $\{B_t\}_{t\geq 0}$ is Brownian motion, then you should be able to determine the value of $f_t=f(B_t)$ for some Borel-measurable function $f$ (for example $ f_t=B_t^2$ or $f_t=e^{B_t}$) form the information in $\mathcal{F}_t$, because $\mathcal{F}_t$ contains $\sigma(B_t)$, which determines $B_t$ almost everywhere.

So even before mentioning the integral, the martingale property is quite useful. Recall also that when choosing the left endpoint in the Ito integral definition of a simple process $\Delta(t)$
$$\int_0^t\Delta(s)dB_s = \sum_{j=0}^{k-1}\Delta(t_j)(B_{t_{j+1}}-B_{t_j})+\Delta(t)(B_{t}-B_{t_k}),\label{1}\tag{1}$$
you do not 'peak into the future', everything is determined from $\mathcal{F}_t$. There is nice point of view in [Stochastic Calculus for Finance II: Continuous-Time Models](https://link.springer.com/book/9780387401010) by Shreve that one can adopt to understand the Ito integral of simple processes:

> Regard $B_t$ as the
> price per share of an asset at time $t$. (Since Brownian motion can take negative
> as well as positive values, it is not a good model of the price of a limited­
> liability asset such as a stock. For the sake of this illustration, we ignore that
> issue.) Think of $t_0,t_1,\ldots,t_{n-1}$ as the trading dates in the asset, and think
> of $\Delta(t_0) , \Delta(t_1 ), \ldots , \Delta (t_n - 1 )$ as the position (number of shares) taken in the
> asset at each trading date and held to the next trading date ($\Delta$ is a simple process). The Ito integral in \eqref{1} is defined as the gain from trading in the martingale $B_t$. A martingale has no tendency to rise or fall, and hence it is to be
> expected that $I(t)$, thought of as a process in its upper limit of integration $t$,
> also has no tendency to rise or fall.

You can follow up form here.

Comment: @Thomas This answer is directed towards the previous version of your question, I still haven't read the recent update.

Comment: Upvoted. In the last part would you say that modelling pricing assets using a stratonovich condition would than be wrong from an economic point of view because would not respect the martingale condition?

Comment: @Thomas Exactly